# UIManager.put not working I my JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

```
UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.red);
```

It's not working in my program. I tried many codes, am new to Java Swing, I don't know whether it's a problem with my code or place where I placed the code.

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   public NewJFrame() {
        UIManager.put("TabbedPane.selected", Color.red);
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). To turn that into an MCVE / SSCCE would mean removing all the irrelevant code, and adding a `main(..)` method and the imports. Then copy the code to a new project and check it compiles and runs without any changes. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: What L&F? Some ignore `"TabbedPane.selected"`.

Comment: This seems to be peculiarity of the `Nimbus` L&F. The `Metal` and `Motif` L&F honor `"TabbedPane.selected"`, but `Nimbus` does not.